# How to toggle css media queries on and off

Tags: css

I am trying to set up link at the bottom of my website like this:

```
Regular view | Mobile view
```

Right now the css file contains media query for regular and mobile views so it automatically adjusts depending on the screen size. How can i let the user control that with the links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put all of the media queries in one file, you can disable them with this:

```
document.getElementById('my-css-file').disabled = true;
```

**[Live demo here (click).](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mv3PPrTHovkHO78l1Mf2?p=preview)**

Comment: I forgot to mention, all my css is on one page, I read somewhere it is recommended to keep everything on as less pages as possible to maximize performance in terms of speed. Is there a way to do what your demo does with one css file?

Comment: @user3233664 well, of course not with that solution. One css file is definitely better, but it's not so bad to add one more. I'll update if I find a better way.

Comment: yeah if you can find how to do with one css file that would be great, other wise i have to a javascript or php file checking which css to load and that will take even more performance time of the website. that's for your help!

Comment: any idea on how to do this?

Comment: @Bamba I believe this is the only way. In the future, there may be support for actually disabling only the queries from a file, but not presently. It would be something like `document.getElementById('my-css-file').mediaStyles.disabled`. I hope they implement that!